# useState not updating nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that uses a React hook to setup an initial array of users. The array subsequently gets rendered on the screen in the form of a list. Every time a button is clicked, a new element is appended to the end of the array. The update gets rendered to the screen correctly.

I also have another component that receives this array and should for now replicate the same behaviour but unfortunately the update does not get rendered. Code for both below.

I've read about shallow and deep copies but seems that's not the cause because it works in the parent component correctly. I specifically initialise a new array in the `setUsers` hook to create a new reference. Code for both below:

Parent Component

```
import { Button, List } from "grommet";
import { Add } from "grommet-icons";
import { useState } from "react";

import Pending from "./Pending";

export default () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    { key: 1, name: "Alan", amount: 20 },
    { key: 2, name: "Bryan", amount: 30 },
    { key: 3, name: "Chris", amount: 40 },
    { key: 4, name: "Eric", amount: 80 }
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        primary
        label="Add"
        icon={<Add />}
        onClick={(e) => {
          const newUser = {
            key: Date.now(),
            name: "Adam",
            amount: 30
          };
          setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, newUser]);
        }}
      />
      <List primaryKey="name" secondaryKey="amount" data={users} />
      <Pending data={users} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Nested Component

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { List } from "grommet";

export default (props) => {
  const [users] = useState(props.data);

  return (
    <>
      <List primaryKey="name" secondaryKey="amount" data={users} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Any ideas for what could be causing this. I'm new to React in general so would appreciate an explanation of why this happens on top of an actual solution.

Comment: `users` is only set to the initial value passed to `useState(props.data)` on the initial render of your child component. If `props.data` changes on subsequent rerenders, it won't change the `users` value as it's already been set on the initial render, it will only change by calling the state setter function. It doesn't look like you need state in your second component and can instead refer to `props.users` directly

Comment: @NickParsons that makes sense. So just to double check, even though the nested component is re-rendered (which I've observed through console.logs) the only thing that would cause its state to change is an explicit call to it's own `setState` hook, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you can also see this by doing `const [num, setNum] = useState(Math.random());` and then cause that component with the `num` state to rerender multiple times. You'll see that it'll print the same number each time. Even though `Math.random()` is producing a new value each re-render and passing it to `useState()`, it'll only ever use the first value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You took the initial `props.data` and put in the state.
Later, when the props changed, you did not change the state - the users being rendered are still those from the state, rather than the updated ones from the props.
That is, if at first you have

```js
props.data === users === [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

After adding a user you get

```js
props.data === [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] !== [1, 2, 3, 4] === users
```

In a case like this, you don't need a `useState` - just render the data from `props` directly. That was the component will update every time its props change.

```js
import { List } from "grommet";

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <List primaryKey="name" secondaryKey="amount" data={props.data} />
    </>
  );
};
```